# Workbox Webpack Plugin and Webpack Dev Server issue

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack-dev-server, iis-express, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm starting to use `webpack-workbox-plugin` to inject `service worker` into `application`. My `project` is an `ASP.NET Core web application` that runs over `IIS Express`.

This is my **development** `webpack config file`:

```js
const MODULE_BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './wwwroot/dist/assets/');
const workboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');

process.env.NODE_ENV = "development";

const config = {
    mode: "development",
    target: "web",
    devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
    context: __dirname, // string (absolute path!)
    entry: [
        '@babel/polyfill',
        'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss',
        './wwwroot/js/main.js',
    ],
    output: {
        path: MODULE_BUILD_DIR,
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
    },

// ...

  plugins: [
    // ...
    new workboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
      swDest: 'sw.js',
      clientsClaim: true,
      skipWaiting: true,
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
      contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
      historyApiFallback: false,
      inline: true,
      open: false,
      port: 9099,
      hot: true,
      https: true,
  },

// ...

}
```

And this is the function i call over my `main.js`:

```js
export default function setServiceWorker() {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then((registration) => {
          console.log('SW registered: ', registration);
        }).catch((registrationError) => {
          console.log('SW registration failed: ', registrationError);
        });
      });
    }
}
```

But when i run `application`, `client` doesn't find `sw.js` file becuse it's allocated over `webpack dev server path`, so not in `IIS Express app path`.

`DevTool` messages:

```
A bad HTTP response code (500) was received when fetching the script.
---
SW registration failed:  TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker
for scope ('https://localhost:44357/') with script ('https://localhost:44357/sw.js'):
A bad HTTP response code (500) was received when fetching the script.
```

What could be a solution for it?
Thank you

Comment: Hello! Please add your solution as an answer instead of editting the question, it will help the organization of SO. (You can also accept your answer after 48h, if i remember correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using `clean-webpack-plugin` and `write-file-webpack-plugin`:

```js
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
        swDest: 'sw.js',
        clientsClaim: true,
        skipWaiting: true,
    }),
    new WriteFilePlugin(),
],
```

but not sure it's the best way